# Why are Meta sites' "site_state" = "linked_meta"?

Tags: feature-request, api-v2, sites

In 2.0 there are the `site_type` and `site_state` fields. On Meta sites these fields give the same information, `site_type = meta_site` and `site_state = linked_meta`

Instead it would be more useful if `linked_meta` was removed, and instead `site_state` shows whether the site is in closed or open beta or normal.

I can't see any reason for this duplication?

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe `linked_meta` means that the meta site is linked to a main site as it is normal for SE sites, i.e. no independent user accounts and reputation. While Meta.SO is a meta site but is independent in these regards from SO.

Comment: Meta.SO is not listed as a meta site at all in the API, not in site_type or site_state. the two fields are duplicates concerning meta sites.